# React, TypeError (this.props.data.map is not a function) on an Array obj

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, redux

Thank you for stopping by to help. I am working with a react/redux app. One of the component is using a lifecyle method to retrieve data from an API. Once recieved, the data JSON data is held within an array. My initialState for the data coming back is an empty array.

When the component listening to the state change is mounted, the data is rendered on to the page, but then 2 seconds later I am getting a

```
Uncaught TypeError: jobs.map is not a function
```

Component making the API call using lifecyle method and listening for state change

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getJobs } from '../../actions';
import { Card, Grid, Image, Feed } from 'semantic-ui-react';
// import './home.css';

const renderJobs = jobs => jobs.map((job, i) => (
    <Card.Group stackable key={i}>
      <Card className="jobscard">
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header href={job.detailUrl} target="_blank">{job.jobTitle}</Card.Header>
          <Card.Meta>{job.location}</Card.Meta>
          <Card.Description>{job.company}</Card.Description>
        </Card.Content>
      </Card>
    </Card.Group>
    ));

class GetJobs extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getJobs();
  }

  render() {
    const { jobs } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="getjobs">
        {renderJobs(jobs)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(({ jobs }) => ({ jobs }), { getJobs })(GetJobs);
```

Action creator/action

```
export const getJobsRequest = () => fetch('https://shielded-brushlands-43810.herokuapp.com/jobs',
)
 .then(res => res.json());

// action creator
export const getJobs = () => ({
  type: 'GET_JOBS',
  payload: getJobsRequest(),
});
```

Reducer

```
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function (jobs = initialState.jobs, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_JOBS_PENDING':
      return { ...jobs, isFetching: true };
    case 'GET_JOBS_FULFILLED':
      return action.payload;
    case 'GET_JOBS_REJECTED':
      return jobs;
    default:
      return jobs;
  }
}
```

And intial state

```
export default {
  userData: {},
  jobs: [],
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHbic.png)

any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Try adding default parameter. Instead of `const renderJobs = jobs => jobs.map((job, i)...` do `const renderJobs = (jobs = []) => jobs.map((job, i)...` and check if it still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a simple check to ensure that your **jobs** is ready before you attempt rendering it.

```
{jobs.length && renderJobs(jobs)}
```

Comment: that did! I thought that was the case, my component was attempting to render an empty array. Thanks so much.

Comment: It doesn't help much. Empty array passed to the `renderJobs` function would still work. And if it's not an array then `jobs.length` check woul fail as well.

Comment: Happy it helped.You can accept the answer if you wouldn't mind

Comment: @Rowland, newb question but how do I accept your answer? lol, I'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: @Jimmyweb, Rowland's answered worked on my end. And, the jobs object is set to an array. Check the initial value.

Comment: @jimmyweb, array is the data type returned. You can check the initial state and see if your concern is handled

Comment: @Rowland, there you go. Thanks for the swift reply. It saves me a lot of time